# what battery(s) do i need to power a 12 amp 200 mph motor for 1 hour?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, motor

I have a plug in leaf blower/vacuum and would like to convert it to battery power. here is a link to the equipment in question. [http://www.amazon.com/Factory-Reconditioned-Ryobi-ZRRY42110-Electric-Mulcher/dp/B004NC014Q/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004NC014Q). 12amp is its maximum output and i don't necessarily need it running that high but would like to know if it is possible to simply wire it to a 24v battery and still use it for at least an hour?

Comment: With the reviews on that thing it sounds as though you're better off getting a new battery-powered device instead.

Comment: Definitely not worth the effort or cost to make the conversion.

Comment: That's a 1440 Watt leaf blower... 12 Amps at 120V

Comment: I would recommend getting a 6V, 12V or 24V (depending on what battery you want to use) DC motor instead if you plan on running it on a battery. Using a DC -> AC converter for this sort of job would be very inefficient, compared to DC-Power -> DC-Battery.

Comment: You could wire 10 12V 15Ah deep-cycle SLA batteries in series.. but that's around 100lbs/$400 worth of batteries.

Comment: I'd use a garden rake to tidy up the leaves - it's much more ecological and doesn't use electricity at all other than what your brain produces to control your arms and legs.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is clearly running off a power cord, you cannot just connect it to a 24 volt battery and expect it to run properly. The motor is probably a universal AC/DC motor, so it might well run from a battery, but it would need to be 120 volts. If you use an inverter, you could do that. Ignoring inverter losses, you would need to provide 120 amps, so for one hour's operation you'd need at least a 120 Ahr battery. And if you're thinking of using lead-acid, you should never discharge more than 50%, so you would need a 240 Ahr battery.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that leaf blower is designed to take AC power in which case it couldn't be powered by battery by any simple means. That leaf blower uses 120*12 = 1440 watts. At 24 volts you would need 60 amps, and to power it for an hour you would need a 60 amp hour battery (aka 25 of [these](http://www.lowes.com/pd_10386-70-DW0242_0__?productId=3511188))

Even if you could figure out battery size you would have to buy an AC to DC converter. I think you would be hard pressed to find a small portable converter able to put out that many amps. There would also be energy losses in the conversion, which would necessitate a larger battery.

If you need a cordless leaf blower it would be best to buy one.